# How to handle and call diffrent version API in google endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How to define different versions in Google endpoints in Java using annotations and how to call them? By theory I know that I need to make different class with @Api and then to define the element version.

```
    @Api(name = "myApi",
     version = "v1",

public class YourFirstAPI {

    /** A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
        response.setData("Hi, " + name);

        return response;
    }

}



@Api(name = "myApi2",
         version = "v2",

    public class YourFirstAPI2 {

        /** A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back */
        @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
        public MyBean sayHi(@Named("name") String name) {
            MyBean response = new MyBean();
            response.setData("Hi, " + name);

            return response;
        }

    }
```

Is this good way to define the APIs like this or there is a better way to do it?
When I want to use v1 or v2 just I have to do it by calling the specific name of the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can feel free to go ahead and name the API the same name, and just change the version name. That's the beauty of version names :)

Depending on the client calling the API, no matter where it's based, in a [Java runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android), in a [javascript library in the browser](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js), whether [building an object to interact with the API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/access_from_python), or constructing a URL and calling the API in a directly RESTful manner using HTTP, the way to specify which version of the API you want to access will be described in the relevant documentation.